# Variables inside functions, can't be used outside the functions

Tags: python

It wont recognize the "text" variables in the if statements. How to change it so when I type in something in the input, it would recognize it and print the thing I want it to print. After that the input message would show again, and you could change the text?

```
print("TYPING SIMULATOR 1.0")
print("______________________")


def type():
    text = input("type something: ")
    print(text)

type()

if "begin" in text or "start" in text:
    print("Game Started!")
    type()

    if "rob" in text:
        print("you get money")
        type()
```

Comment: You need to pass it as a parameter to the type() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the game to run until you enter 'exit' or something similar you could do it like this:

```
print("TYPING SIMULATOR 1.0")
print("______________________")

while True:
    def type():
        text = input("type something: ")
        return(text)

    text = type()

    if "begin" in text or "start" in text:
        print("Game Started!")
        text = type()

        if "rob" in text:
            print("you get money")
            text = type()
    
    if text == "exit":
        print("Exiting Game!")
        break
```

Answer (score 3):

You can always `return` the value of the function, and check the result

```
print("TYPING SIMULATOR 1.0")
print("______________________")


def type():
    text = input("type something: ")
    return text 

text=type()

if "begin" in text or "start" in text:
    print("Game Started!")
    text=type()

    if "rob" in text:
        print("you get money")
        text=type()
```

Comment: You forgot the two other type(), using `text = type()` :-)

Comment: It does work but as I would like to add multiple possible texts to write and the "type something" text only pops up twice and then it finishes the process. How can I do it that it always shows the "type something:" text when i have wrote something in the last one?

Comment: @oneminer I edited my post to reflect the change you mentioned in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you're trying to get the value given by the `input` function.
So the better way to do that is :

```py
def get_input() -> str:
    return input("type something: ")

text: str = get_input()
```